# Error 6017: The NavigationProperty '(propertyname)' on the type '(typename)' is the source of

Tags: sql-server-2005, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

`Error 6017: The NavigationProperty '(propertyname)' on the type '(typename)' is the source of a generated property '(otherpropertyname)' which conflicts with a member of the same name.`

OK, I'm fairly certain I understand why I'm getting this error message, but it is not obvious to me how to work around it.

I have a table `salesreps` which links to a table `territories` with a simple foreign key relationship.  The `territories` table gets updated via an automated feed, whereas the salesreps table is manually maintained through a web interface I am designing.

I don't want the reps to be deleted if the territory goes away; I intend to highlight them for manual corrective action in the UI I am building as orphaned reps needing a territory assignment.

The sales reps are defined by an ID that is only unique with a given territory (nothing I can do about this, way outside my control), if a territory is removed, I made the foreign key `ON DELETE` behavior set the `territoryID` value to null, and made the column nullable.  I then created a computed column called `territoryReferenceID` on the `salesreps` table set to `isnull(territoryID, 0)`, made it persisted, and created the primary key based off the `repID` and the `territoryReferenceID` columns, since I cannot make a nullable PK column (which I still think is lame, even if I understand why it is).  In the database, this works fine, and if somehow two territories are deleted with the same repID at the same time (highly unlikely) I'm ok with a primary key violation error that I can trap.

Mapping this to EF gives me the aforementioned error.  I don't know why EF has a problem with this, and I don't know how to make the problem go away.  I want to keep the behavior as designed in the database schema.

How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

I removed the relationships in the entity model and the navigation properties, intending to just use the key ids directly.  This worked, until the next time I updated the model from the database, where it reintroduced the relationship and threw the error.

So I made a view of the data with only one `territoryID` column (referencing the computed column) and created stored procedures for creating, modifying, and removing records from the view.

This works.  It's ugly, but that's what I get for trying to "save time" with EF.